# MacOS + TypeC USB Converter - Port shown as disabled in arduino studio

Tags: macos, arduino, port

Last week i've changed my macbook from late 2015 to new touch bar edition (with type-c port)

I've installed FTDI drivers and other CHXXX drivers from internet.

I connect my Ardunio R3 UNO Board (original) over  Usb-c 3.1 Hdmi Usb converter.

Mac identify my Arduino Board but arduino studio i can not select PORTs

How can i fix this issue. Thanks a lot,

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
user$ ls -1 /dev/tty.*
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
/dev/tty.MALS
/dev/tty.SOC
/dev/tty.usbmodem143101
```